# Sharepoint online Searching file can't open from results 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: sharepoint

do you have any ideas?
I just create our new Sharepoint (online) intranet with new document library. Uploaded new files and reindexed. And now when I try to search something I have results, but can't open it (error message 404 NOT FOUND), but only on some files (specially .pdf formats).

Did someone have same issues? Or do you know best practises for build Document Library and setup searching in Sharepoint?

And do you know how long takes full reindex? (I just uploaded 3pcs of .pdfs)

I tried:
- reindex site,
- rename files,
- remove and upload files,

Comment: Are the files checked in? is the document library configured with versioning? Try to checkin/publish files just in case that fixes the problem.

Comment: I will try that and versioning is on (versions 1.0,2.0etc)

Comment: Gonzix I tried it, nothing then I tried reindex.No luck...

Comment: If you upload any other text file (docx, txt...), do they get indexed properly? if yes, is there any difference between each URL? I mean, 404 is a not found exception, whats the difference between the URL from the search index and the one you get manually from the library? does it work If you manually type the URL for the pdf ? Can you edit your question adding the URL form the search and the one you would type to get the file manually?